# How to create network file based on IP address from file similar to /etc/hosts

Tags: bash, mapping, hostname, hosts

I have a file which maps IP address to hostnames. Its format is similar to hosts file and contains a list of IP address to hostname mapping.

eg.

```
10.200.99.1    master1
10.200.99.2    master2
10.200.99.3    master3
10.200.99.4    slave1
10.200.99.5    slave2
10.200.99.6    slave3
...
...
...
```

I would like to create network file (`/etc/sysconfig/network`) for all the IP address mentioned in the file.

The format of network file is where the hostname is mentioned based on hosts file.

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=master1
NOZEROCONF=yes
```

For every IP Address the network file is created in a directory named by IP Address i.e. `network/{IPAddress}`.

For example for `master1` the path of file should be `network/10.200.99.1` and for `master2` the path should be `network/10.200.99.2`.

How can i do so?

Till now I have obtained IPAdress by following command `echo $(<hosts) | awk '{print $1}'` and Hostname by `echo $(<hosts) | awk '{print $2}`. But this only prints the contents of first line of the hosts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reads *ip* and *hostname* from `hosts` and writes desired output to `network/$ip`.

```
while read ip hostname; do
    printf '%s\n' "NETWORKING=yes" "HOSTNAME=$hostname" "NOZEROCONF NF=yes" > network/$ip
done < hosts
```